# Good IDE for GNU Octave?

Tags: software, octave, software-recommendation

Are there any good IDEs for working with Octave code?

I'm used to type hints and documentation preview from software like IntelliJ or VS Code. While there are syntax highlighting plugins for VSC, all that isn't quite there yet, so is there a better solution?

Comment: GNU Octave has a great GUI with syntax highlighting, code-completion and every thing. Why you need a third-party IDE?

Answer (score 3):

QtOctave ([source1](https://github.com/luisivan/QtOctave/), [source2](https://github.com/mtmiller/qtoctave/)) among many others like [OctaveOnline](https://octave-online.net/), Jupyter Notebook, Emacs, Sublime Text, VS Code, etc. support Octave code editing, syntax highlighting, and more.

> `QtOctave` also provides code-completion, which is mostly not available in many others.